# Is Table splitting is more efficient?

Tags: sql

I’m working on a project using an SQL database and gathering a large amount of information from users (approximately 20 users!). What would be more time efficient while analysing the data:

1. Separate the data into table per user.
2. Containing all the data in one table.

Important: the database must be SQL and the searching is by user and no other criteria. in addition, the data per user is around 1TB.
What's more efficient – 20 1TB tables, or one 20TB table?

Comment: Apart from 1 and 2 you could group the kind of user data into specific tables. Please provide some examples of what kind of user data you would be storing to get to 1TB per user?

Comment: I suggest youpost this on the SO site for database administrators.  I think more detail will be needed as well (for starters, what database management program are you using?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when this type of question is asked, the answer is easy.  Storing the data in a single table is the best option.  But, usually users are not talking about a *terabyte* of data per user.  Even if you had gigabytes or tens of gigabytes of data per user, one table would be the easier route.

The question is how you intend to analyze the data.  If you are analyzing one user at a time, then separate tables are fine.  You *can* store the data in a single table.  If so, I would suggest that you look into "partitions" so each user can go into its own data store.

Managing even 20 tables can be a pain -- if you add an index to one for performance, you then have to repeat the process 19 more times.  On the other hand, being able to backup and restore one user's data may be beneficial.  It turns out that vertical partitioning can solve both these problems reasonably.

Without knowing how you intend to do the analysis or the database your are using, my bias would be toward a vertically partitioned single table, with one partition per user.

Answer (score 0):

20 is a small amount of users. Also I find it hard to believe you have 20TB of data. Say you end up with 1000 users. 1000 tables will quickly become unmanageable.

The data structure used in RDBMS (B+ tree, etc) is optimized for large amounts of data. It continues to scale. Use an index for a user id, and 1 table.

If the only lookup value is a user id, also consider nosql type database (mongodb).

Answer (score 0):

That depends on a lot of factors. Usually, there is no way to answer such a question. You should really create the database, fill it with test data and do some performance tests (i.e. run a couple of standard queries) to see how fast things are.

Most of the time, you'll find that most operations are fast enough but some weird corner case kills you.

Generally speaking, when you put all data into a single table, then the DB server will have to skip the rows for the other users. Skipping 19TB of data is something that you'll probably notice but it depends on how the DB server organizes the data internally, how big the rows are, and about 999 other factors.

That said, if you don't plan to query the data by column ("searching is by user and no other criteria"), dumping this into an SQL database is probably the wrong design. A plain file on a harddisk (i.e. one file per user) sounds like a much better solution - unless you omitted some important fact.

Note: "my boss told me so" isn't a fact.